# generate series at 15 minute interval but skip every other week

Tags: sql, postgresql, intervals, generate-series

I need to `generate_series` with 15-minute interval. The caveat is i need it to skip every other week.

This is what i have so far which gets the series in 15-minute intervals **but** not to omit every other week

```
select i from generate_series('2017-01-01', '2017-12-31', '15 minutes'::interval) as g(i);
```

I'm also able to `generate_series` for every other week:

```
select i from generate_series('2017-12-31', '2017-01-01', '-2 week'::interval) as g(i)
```

just need help putting both together: *to get 15-minutes interval for but skipping every other week*

sample outcome:

```
timestamp
----------------------
2017-01-01 00:00:00+00
2017-01-01 00:15:00+00
2017-01-01 00:30:00+00
...
2017-01-15 00:45:00+00
2017-01-15 01:00:00+00
2017-01-15 01:15:00+00
...
2017-01-29 00:30:00+00
2017-01-29 00:45:00+00
2017-01-29 01:00:00+00
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two *loops* - one for a first day of week and the other for 15 minutes intervals inside the week. In SQL cross join is used to implement *nested loops:*

```
select tstamp
from generate_series('2017-01-01', '2017-12-31', '2 week'::interval) as start_of_week
cross join generate_series(start_of_week::date, start_of_week::date+ '1 week'::interval, '15 min'::interval) as tstamp
```

Comment: that's good to know on the cross join method. works like a charm. thanks

Comment: how could i tweak it to generate for only hours between **18:00 - 6:00** and omit all hours not within that time frame?

`generate_series('2017-01-01 18:00'::timestamp, '2017-12-31 06:00'::timestamp, '15 minutes'::interval) as g(i)`

Comment: If you want to get only halves of days from 18:00 use: `where (tstamp- interval '18h')::time between '0:00' and '12:00'`